# Show multiple month in bootstrap daterange picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to modify the bootstrap daterangepicker. I want to show 12 months instead of 2. Here is my code:

```
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
 "startDate": "04/17/2018",
 "endDate": "04/23/2018",
 "numberOfMonths": 12
}, function(start, end, label) {
console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to 
 ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');
});
```

However it's not working. Can anyone please help.

Comment: According to the docs, you can't.  You can use the `linkedCalendars` option to make it so each month can independently scroll though.

Comment: ok, but this option can only show 2 months. i want to show 4 months.

Comment: Like I said, according to the docs you can't.  If you want that ability you either need to roll your own daterangepicker or modify the underlying code in daterangepicker